# ASP.net Core EF DataContext not Scoped as per Documentation?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my Startup.cs file, I have set up a data context to participate in DI.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
      services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
      {
           options.UseSqlServer("Connection String");
      });  
 }
```

According to [Dependency Injection Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection), the above code automatically puts the data context as Scoped in the IoC container. I am under the impression that an instance of MyDbContext is created for every request. A subsequent request would then have a new MyDbContext instance throughout its lifetime.

I have a controller set up and I'm passing MyDbContext via constructor DI. I make a simple GET request, and I get the data I want. I make a change to that very entity in SQL Management Studio, like change the value of one property/column. I make that same GET request. I don't get the new value that I set in SQL Management Studio.

This makes me think that ASP.net Core holds on to the same instance of MyDbContext across the lifetime of my application. If I stopped and restarted the application, that GET request will return the value I expected.

How do I refresh this data context for each request if I set it up with DI?

Am I missing something? I might post more code if needed.

Comment: Post your Startup.cs class, at least the bits involving EF/DbContext. Do you seed data during startup? If so, how do you resolve the DbContext? For seeding check the SO Documentation here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-core/1949/dependency-injection/17400/using-scoped-services-during-application-startup-database-seeding#t=201611222059047079754 You must create a scope if you resolve seed in startup.cs

Comment: What's posted above is the only part of Startup.cs that involves EF/DbContext. No, I don't seed.

Comment: How are you calling the dbcontext in the controller?

Comment: public class MyController { private MyDbContext db {get; set; } public MyController(MyDbContext context) { db = context; } ... }. I just create a parameter of type MyDbContext in the constructor and the system gives me access to the data context.

Comment: Show your Startup and DbContext code; please read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1112848/Creating-Web-API-in-ASP-NET-Core

Comment: set a breakpoint in your `MyController`, see if it hits the breakpoint when you send the request again? I suspect a certain caching issue...